# How do you turn off notification sounds on LG G4?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, lg-g4

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to turn off the notification sounds. I found the option in settings for the notification sounds, but none of the options are to turn it off or silence it, without silencing the whole phone!

Comment: "Alternatively, you can set system sounds to silent (settings -> sounds -> volume). That includes notifications, annoying boot noise and audio touch feedback.
I don't know what else it turns off, but whatever it is, I don't miss it.
With this approach you can keep the priorities logic intact."

That was taken from this post. Maybe it will help.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/g4/help/mute-volume-notifications-leave-phone-t3141244

Comment: @jer3my Lowering the volume setting will also lower the ringtone. I DON'T want to mute the ringtone, only the notifications.

Comment: Hmm I have only ever had samsung phones(besides the one htc I dont count... lol) and when I adjust the volume on mine, It does change all of them, However if I click on the gear, I can change each one to whatever level. http://i.imgur.com/4Msh4gk.jpg

Its weird that LG would make it all or nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I think I figured it out. It's this whole stupid interruption mode feature. Setting the phone to Priority Only, and then enabling all incoming calls and messages achieves the same result as disabling the notification sounds. This is a horrible design IMHO.

Comment: Also have a look here : http://recomhub.com/blog/how-to-mute-lg-g4/

Comment: I looked at that post, but all the information is incorrect. There are no buttons on the left side of the G4; the author is confused. The volume and power key are on the BACK of the device. And holding the volume down key DOES NOT accomplish what the author says it does.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings, sound and notifications, apps. Then select which apps give you notifications and how they do it (sounds, notification bar etc)

Answer (score 0):

Use a silent tone, meaning a notification tone that doesn't include any noise. You might find some [here](http://jetcityorange.com/silent-ringtone/).

Answer (score 0):

Go into the email app, click the three dots in a row, select settings, select the email account you will see notification settings; select silent

Answer (score 0):

The one person above had the correct answer.  You have to go into your email account, click the three dots on top left, choose settings, and then click the account you want to change.  In there is a notification setting where you can silence the notification.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is more of a comment. It also does NOT address the question. I am not trying to mute my email app, I am trying to mute all notifications.